Runge-Kutta 4 code: no 4th order improvement
In short: in a specific physics problem, my Runge-Kutta 4th order code doesn't produce the desired and expected fourth order improvement when I reduce the iteration step size. What is the cause?
In simple physics problems, I use Runge-Kutta 4th order code to calculate an approximate numerical 'solution' to a differential equation. The numerical result converges to some specific value each time when I reduce the step size, which is often a time step $\text{d}t$. (The value can be verified if an analytical solution to the differential equation exists.) When I reduce the step size by a factor of 1/10, the difference between the last two calculated values is reduced by a factor of $1/10^4$. Fine, that's what I understand to be a global fourth order improvement.
As a simple example: a mass-spring system in harmonic, horizontal oscillation is described by Newton's second law $F_\text{res}=m\cdot a$ where the resultant force is $F_\text{res}=F_\text{spring}=-C\cdot x$ according to Hooke's law (no friction), $x$ is the displacement from the equilibrium position and the acceleration is $a=\frac{\text{d}^2 x}{\text{d}t^2}=\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}$. So we have the second order differential equation $-C\cdot x=m\cdot \frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2}$ and $\text{d}x=v\cdot\text{d}t$ and $\text{d}v=a\cdot\text{d}t=-(C/m)\cdot x\cdot\text{d}t$. My iteration code is
$$\text{d}x1=v\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v1=-(C/m)\cdot x\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$\text{d}x2=(v+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}v1)\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v2=-(C/m)\cdot(x+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}x1)\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$\text{d}x3=(v+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}v2)\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v3=-(C/m)\cdot(x+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}x2)\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$\text{d}x4=(v+\text{d}v3)\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v4=-(C/m)\cdot(x+\text{d}x3)\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$x=x+\frac{\text{d}x1+2\cdot\text{d}x2+2\cdot\text{d}x3+\text{d}x4}{6}$$
$$v=v+\frac{\text{d}v1+2\cdot\text{d}v2+2\cdot\text{d}v3+\text{d}v4}{6}$$
$$t=t+\text{d}t$$
This scheme also achieves fourth order improvement in other simple physics problems, such as a falling mass with air drag $F_\text{res}=F_\text{gravity}+F_\text{drag}=-m\cdot g+C\cdot v^2$. So far, so good.
I now use similar code to model a collision of two identical steel spheres, each with mass $m$. The resultant force on each sphere according to Heinrich Hertz is $F_\text{res}=-C\cdot h^{3/2}$ where $h$ is the total deformation of the two spheres. With $\mu=m/2$ the reduced mass of the two spheres and some given initial relative velocity $v_0$, the code is
$$\text{d}h1=v\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v1=-(C/\mu)\cdot h^{3/2}\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$\text{d}h2=(v+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}v1)\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v2=-(C/\mu)\cdot(h+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}h1)^{3/2}\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$\text{d}h3=(v+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}v2)\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v3=-(C/\mu)\cdot(h+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot\text{d}h2)^{3/2}\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$\text{d}h4=(v+\text{d}v3)\cdot \text{d}t\hspace{1cm}\text{d}v4=-(C/\mu)\cdot(h+\text{d}h3)^{3/2}\cdot\text{d}t$$
$$h=h+\frac{\text{d}h1+2\cdot\text{d}h2+2\cdot\text{d}h3+\text{d}h4}{6}$$
$$v=v+\frac{\text{d}v1+2\cdot\text{d}v2+2\cdot\text{d}v3+\text{d}v4}{6}$$
$$t=t+\text{d}t$$
I calculate the speed $v_{1/2}$ at the moment when the total deformation $h$ is half the maximum value, $h_{1/2}=\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot h_\text{max}$.
I repeat the calculation, each time with a step size $\text{d}t$ which is 1/10 times the previous step size. With each step size reduction, the code calculates a better approximation of the correct $v_{1/2}$, which can be found independently from the energy equation. BUT a step size reduction by a factor of 1/10 now only reduces the difference between the last two values of $v_{1/2}$ by a factor of $1/10^{2.50}$ instead of the expected $1/10^4$. In each run, the calculation of $v_{1/2}$ has at least 1000 iterations (steps). All calculations are done with over 80 digits. The differential equation isn't a stiff differential equation, I guess.
My questions: what causes the improvement to be only by a factor of $1/10^{2.50}$? How can I achieve improvement by a factor of $1/10^4$
Any help would be appreciated.

From the physical description, you want to simulate some very fast and sharp turns. This is usually a stiff ODE. An explicit fixed-step method is maximally unsuited for its numerical solution. From a physical perspective, the sampling density might not be high enough to capture sufficient details of the turn. From a numerical perspective, this is seen as operating outside of the stability region of the method.
From a more specific point-of-view, your ODE function has a limited differentiability at zero. The error coefficients however are polynomials in the partial derivatives of the ODE function. The terms of the Taylor expansions of the method stages can only cancel as long as these terms exist. Thus if the expansion has only a finite degree, then the error will be a combination of the lower-order remainder terms.
Now one could explore how much order there still is in the steps of your numerical integration, the singularities in the derivatives seem to be limited to a finite number of steps. At some point the accumulation of floating-point errors will raise to become an equal error contribution, this imposes a lower bound for the accuracy.

There is a sharp turn near maximum deformation, where the speed changes relatively fast and the motion changes direction. That's why I excluded this second 'half' of the motion. In the first 'half', I see no sharp turn. All quantities change smoothly. Thus, I'm not convinced the ODE is stiff in the first 'half' of the motion.

The point of limited differentiabilty is plausible and is confirmed by further calculations. Modifying the acceleration to -(C/m)*h^(1/2) or -(C/m)*h^(5/2), both with indetermined first derivative at h=0, improve the result according to order 1/2+1 and 5/2+1 respectively, upon reduction of the step size. This now seems logical. Modifying to -(C/m)*h or -(C/m)h^3 or -(C/m)(h+0.001)^(3/2) all restore fourth order improvement. Thank you!
